# error expected specifier-qualifier-list before

Tags: c

I tried to compile this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>

main(){
    size_t distance;

    struct x{
        int a, b, c;
    } s_tr;

    distance = offsetof(s_tr, c);

    printf("Offset of x.c is %lu bytes\n", (unsigned long)distance);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); 
}
```

I got an error: error expected specifier-qualifier-list before 's_tr'. what does it mean? The example i got from: http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter9/introduction.html

Comment: I'm assuming your code says
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>

instead of 

include
include
include

????

Comment: yes, i don't know how to add < or > so I use "" for now. does anyone know how to add < or >?

Comment: If you have a block of text set up as code (i.e. you have indented it at least 4 spaces) then you can just type left and right angle brackets and they will show up correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On second reading, it looks like someone accidentally inserted an `x` before the `{`.  The original probably had an anonymous struct:

```
struct { int a, b, c; } s_tr;
```

You can rewrite it with a typedef like:

```
typedef struct { int a, b, c; } newtype;
newtype s_tr;
```

Here's some code I used to refresh my memory, with the various ways to declare a struct in C (anonymous, tagged, and typed):

```
// Anonymous struct
struct { int a,b; } mystruct1;

// Tagged struct
struct tag1 { int a,b; };
struct tag1 mystruct2; // The "struct" is not optional

// Typedef declaring both tag and new type
typedef struct tag2 { int a, b; } type1;
struct tag2 mystruct3;
type1 mystruct4; // Unlike tags, types can be used without "struct"
```

Comment: The x isn't incorrect, it is the name of the struct. So, in the original question, the type of the struct is `struct x` and the s_tr is simply a syntax error. Also, using something like `struct { int a, b, c; } s_tr;` gives a compiler error, at least on my version of gcc.

Comment: @Paul Wicks: What kind of error does gcc report?  My gcc thinks it's fine.

Comment: `error: syntax error before ‘s_tr’` This is with gcc 4.0.1 (which is, admittedly, a little old).

Comment: @Paul Wicks: This is exactly how the Kernighan & Ritchie book declares structs.  Perhaps gcc 4 does not allow the declaration of structs inside a function.

Answer (score 0):

This code is (as far as I can tell) incorrect. You need to add a typedef to `struct x` if you want to refer to it as s_tr. Otherwise, s_tr doesn't really mean anything (and in my case, won't even compile).

```
 typedef struct x{
     int a, b, c;
 }s_tr;
```

However, this is not required. You could refer to the struct as x, but you have to put the struct keyword in front of it. Like this:

```
distance = offsetof(struct x, c);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>

typedef struct { int a, b, c; } s_tr;

int main(int argc, char **argv){ 

    size_t distance; 

    distance = offsetof(s_tr, c);
    printf("Offset of x.c is %lu bytes\n",
                (unsigned long)distance);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); 
}
```

Also, [this question and answer from the C-FAQ might help your understanding](http://c-faq.com/struct/typedef.html):

Q: What's the difference between these two declarations?

```
struct x1 { ... };
typedef struct { ... } x2;
```

A: The first form declares a structure tag; the second declares a typedef. The main difference is that the second declaration is of a slightly more abstract type--its users don't necessarily know that it is a structure, and the keyword struct is not used when declaring instances of it:

```
x2 b;
```

Structures declared with tags, on the other hand, must be defined with the

```
struct x1 a;
```

form. [footnote]

(It's also possible to play it both ways:

```
typedef struct x3 { ... } x3;
```

It's legal, if potentially obscure, to use the same name for both the tag and the typedef, since they live in separate namespaces. See question 1.29.)

Answer (score 0):

`offsetof()` requires a **type** for the first argument.
You passing it an *object* of type `struct x`.